# How to read a CSV file from a remote server in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read a CSV file from a remote server and I am not sure what is the best way to do it in VB.NET. The csv file is about 600Kbytes.

Should I download the file locally and then read it line by line?

I tried the following code. It can output a small text file, but not my csv file.

```
Dim WebClient As New WebClient()
WebClient.Proxy = Nothing
Dim remotetext As String = WebClient.DownloadString("http://localhost/test.csv")
```

Comment: If it's 600kb, then just continue doing what you're doing, a single 600kb string is negligible.

Comment: http://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/built-in-net-csv-parser/

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Comment: http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/